# How to use root relative path with Eclipse Http Preview server

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp, contextroot

I have Static Web project in Eclipse and using Http Preview server for development. I want to use root relative path in my resources (e.g. `/css/style.css`) but I can't figure out how to configure that server to work. There always needs to be context root in path (e.g. http://localhost:8080/myapp). Context root can't be configured as empty. Is there any option I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this problem if you are working on a Unix variant. It relies on symbolic links, so it probably cannot be made to work on Windows. I claim no points for elegance, but it does seem to work for me on Ubuntu.

First, you create a new static web project in Eclipse that will contain a link to the resource directory. In this case, you can call the project `css`. Alternatively, give it a descriptive name, and change the context root to `css` using the project properties dialog.

In a terminal window, change to the project directory for the newly created project. Probably something like `~/workspace/css/`. Then replace the `WebContent` directory with an appropriate symlink:

```
cd ~/workspace/css
rmdir WebContent
ln -s ../myproject/WebContent/css WebContent
```

Now return to Eclipse and refresh the `css` project. You should now see all of your css files in the project explorer.

Run the `css` project and the original project on the HTTP preview server.

You will have to repeat this process for each of the top-level resource directories.